# Random Module Methods Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

How can I search for all the random module methods in python?
I tried with this code:

```
def random():
    import random
    random.helpm
random()
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've imported the module, you can just do:

`help(modulename)`

...to get the docs on all the functions at once, interactively. Or you can use:

`dir(modulename)`

...to simply list the names of all the functions and variables defined in the module.